# 2 Labels on custom Cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, constraints, custom-cell

I am attempting to add the date/time next to a message in a messenger app. Currently the auto size of the cell works great for the message. However when I try to add a second label to the cell I get a runtime error of terminating with uncaught exception. I am attempting to make the date on the left side of the cell where the current message text is on the right of the cell. Deleting the constraints makes it so the timeLabel is never displayed.

Here is most of the cellforRowatIndexPath method

```
        cell.myLabel.font = font
        cell.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.myLabel.text = self.messages[indexPath.row]

        cell.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        cell.myLabel.textAlignment = .justified

        let marginGuide = cell.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        cell.myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.myLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

        cell.myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cell.myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)

        if size1.width > 260 {
            cell.myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 260
        }
        else{
            cell.myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = size1.width
        }
        let interval = self.timeStamps[indexPath.row]
        if let myDouble = NumberFormatter().number(from: interval)?.doubleValue {
            let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: myDouble)
            cell.timeLabel.font = font
            cell.timeLabel.text = "date"// String(describing: date)
            cell.timeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            cell.timeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            cell.timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            cell.timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        }
```

here is the entire program for the custom cell I created.

```
import UIKit

class messageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var myLabel = UILabel()
var background = UIImageView()
var timeLabel = UILabel()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.contentView.addSubview(background)
    self.contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    myLabel.sizeToFit()
    let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)

    timeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    timeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    timeLabel.sizeToFit()



}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Someone please help me figure out how to add this second label. I have tried everything.

Comment: What line of code is causing the crash?

Comment: The line where I set the constraints for the timeLabel: 
    cell.timeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: And do you get any information in the console about the crash? Do you know what the reason is?

Comment: it says uncaught exception, I am not sure, what the error is.

Comment: Have you tried setting up the cell in storyboard and dequeueing it in cellForRowAtIndexPath? It's much more neater

Answer (score 0):

I made a careless mistake, I forgot to add the subview in my cell class.
I needed this line:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(timeLabel)
```